# Deleting subdirectories without remove their content?

Tags: bash, files, directory

I have a directory called music who have many albums and separate tracks. Some of them are in subdirectories. What I want is remove this folders and mix all tracks in the music directory without separations.

Will be hard do this manually, so I am looking for some [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) command.

Answer (score 2):

#### Without `find`

```
shopt -s globstar
mv -nv **/*.mp3 /path/to/common/directory
```

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -mindepth 1 -type f -exec mv -i "{}" /common/path \;
find . -mindepth 1 -d -type d -exec rmdir "{}" \;
```

This will move all your music from the current directory to `/common/path` and the second one will delete all directories. Then you can move all your stuff back to the original directory.

Also, this will prompt you if you want to overwrite files with the same name.

Comment: Can't I sent the subdirectories files to the music directory directly?

Comment: Not with this method. This will throw an error when you try to move the files from the top level of the structure(trying to move the same file on itself). You could however, use `-mindepth 2` in the first command and replace /common/path with `.`, however, this is opening up for another set of issues(llike having a directory with a name of a file you are moving). It's a bit safer to use a different path(empty one) and handle files with the same name. You may as well use `cp` instead of `mv`, review and delete the original structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
find /path/to/music/ -type f -execdir mv -n "{}" /path/to/sharedmusic/ \;
```

Files with duplicate names will *not* be moved, but rather left in their original location.

Comment: If you find yourself with a copy of `awesome tune.ogg`, would you rather see `mv path/to/awesome tune.ogg /path/to/sharedmusic` or `mv "path/to/awesome tune.ogg" /path/to/sharedmusic`?

Comment: is that a reference to the quotes around `{}`? `find` doesn't run the command through a shell, so that's not an issue there. (`find` doesn't even see the quotes, it just sees `{}` as an argument.) If you had `find -exec sh -c 'somecmd "$1"' sh {} \;`, then the quotes inside the shell scriptlet would be an issue

Answer (score 0):

You could complete a find for all the files in the sub-directories then have that find command execute move to current directory.

an example of this is found in this answer below.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22388480/how-to-pipe-the-results-of-find-to-mv-in-linux

Quoted Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22388545/879882

> `xargs` is commonly used for this, and `mv` has a `-t` option to facilitate that.
>
> ```
> find ./ -name '*article*' | xargs mv -t ../backup
> ```
>
> If your `find` supports `-exec ... \+` you could equivalently do
>
> ```
> find ./ -name '*article*' -exec mv -t ../backup {}  \+
> ```
>
> The `-t` option is probably a GNU extension. It's of course possible to roll your own, maybe something like
>
> ```
> find ./ -name '*article*' -exec sh -c 'mv "$@" "$0"' ../backup {} \+
> ```
>
> where we shamelessly abuse the convenient fact that the first argument after `sh -c 'commands'` ends up as the "script name" parameter in `$0` so that we don't even need to `shift` it.

Comment: @Theophrastus we don't know this is for a Linux system with GNU tools. It could be Mac or Solaris. And the point was that `mv -t` is not [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/mv.html)

Comment: I was pointing to an existing answer to a similar question over on stack overflow and only quoted a section of the answer. if you go to the stack overflow question, its has more explanation then what i put here.

Comment: We're not on stackoverflow

Comment: @roaima I understand this is not Stack Overflow but stack overflow is a stack exchange site like this site, its why I quoted the answer instead of submitting the question as a duplicate question.